# Crash on xcode but not on windows. SIGABRT?

Tags: c

I have to write a program for my C programming class that converts IPV4 addresses into IPV6. We were supplied with the function to do the conversion (the below code does the actual converting). I am having problems in XCode when ever I run this code.  I have used break points and worked out that it is crashing when it hits the `sprintf()` line. It crashes with: `Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all`. I have tested the exact same code on a Windows based compiler and it runs fine. What would cause it to fail on one and not the other? My program hast to run on Windows, not Mac for the grading process of if there is no fix for this then I will make do and write the rest of the program on Windows but I would prefer to use Mac so any help is appreciated.

```
    strncpy(IPV6, "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:", 30); 
    sscanf(input, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &a, &b, &c, &d); 
    sprintf(hexIP, "%02X%02X:%02X%02X", a, b, c, d );
    strncat(IPV6, hexIP, 9);
```

Thanks

EDIT

```
int makeIPV6(const char input[25], char IPV6[40], int style)  
{
        unsigned int a, b, c, d, e, f;
        char hexIP[9];
        char hexMAC[24];
        printf("Stage 2\n");
        strncpy(IPV6, "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:", 30);
        sscanf(input, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        sprintf(hexIP, "%02X%02X:%02X%02X", a, b, c, d );
        strncat(IPV6, hexIP, 9);

        return strlen(IPV6)
}
```

Comment: Do you know what compilers you're using? In Xcode you can do **Get Info** on your project and check the build settings. What compiler are you using on Windows?

Comment: Could you post your variable declarations?  It seems you're invoking undefined behavior that works in Windows by coincidence.

Comment: On Mac it is GCC4.2 (i think) and windows in think it is mingw (i use quincy so whatever it uses)

Comment: (1) How big is `IPV6`. (2) Is `IPV6` initialized to all zero bytes? (3) How big is `hexIP`?

Comment: Well i fixed the issue, i changed the hexIP from 9 to 10, not sure why it worked on windows but all that matters is it works

Comment: OSX is probably being a little stricter with stack smashing than Windows. Rearrange the order of your variable declarations and you could probably make it crash (with `char hexIP[9];`) on Windows too. Also watch out for nul terminator issues with `IPV6`, its initial value may be compiler/OS dependent so `memset` it to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a buffer overflow:

```
char hexIP[9];
/*...*/
sprintf(hexIP, "%02X%02X:%02X%02X", a, b, c, d );
```

Your format string will yield 9 characters but `sprintf` will include the nul terminator. Try making `hexIP` ten characters.

And pay attention to what Joey Adams said or `memset(IPV6, '\0', 40)` before you try to put anything in it.

Answer (score 4):

You have fallen fowl of `strncpy`'s annoying caveat, namely that if a null terminator is not among the first n bytes of the **source** string, no terminator will be appended to the output buffer.

```
char buffer[999];
strcpy(buffer, "xxxxxxxxxx");
strncpy(buffer, "12345", 5);
puts(buffer);
```

This prints `12345xxxxx` rather than `12345`.

When you see `strncpy`, warning bells should go off in your head.  In this case, you're better off just saying:

```
strcpy(IPV6, "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:");
```

With your current code, a null terminator may or may not appear at the end of the IPV6 string.